# How to test the set method of @Input in an Angular directives

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm new to Angular testing. I have to test the set and get method of `@Input` in an Angular directive. But I have no idea on how to implement it. Any help is appreciated.

```js
import { Directive, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import {myService } from './../../../internal-service/myservice.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirectivekey]'
})
export class myDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private conf;

  @Input()
  set key(key) {
    if (key) {
      this.conf = key;
    }
  }

  get key() { return this.conf; }

  constructor(private myServic: myServic) { }

}
```

Comment: It's a class. Call its constructor. The set the value of its key property, then test that its key property has the expected value.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, I'll just create a new instance of your directive and since you want to test `set` and `get`, I'll set `myServic` to null.

Check this test

```
describe('should set conf', () => {
    const testDirective = new myDirective(null);

    const testValue = 'test';

    testDirective.key = testValue; // this will call set key
    expect(testDirective.key).toEqual(testValue); // this will call get key

    testDirective.key = null; // test whether if(key) works
    expect(testDirective.key).toEqual(testValue); // since, we just passed a null, it should not set the value.
});
```